# Conditional Text Join on Columns in MySQL. Some Phrases Exact Match and others Regex

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to join two tables - let's call them `table1` and `table2` - in MySQL based on a text column in each table.  `table1.text` is all sentences, and I need to join on `table2.text` where the word or phrase from `table2.text` appears in the sentence for table one.

The tricky part is if the phrase from `table2.text` is surrounded by `**`, then it needs to be an exact match for that word.  If not and it's just a normal phrase, it can be a regex match - so a word like `can` in `table2.text` would match the sentence `I have cans` in `table1.text`.  However, `**can**` in `table2.text` would not `I have cans` in `table1.text`.

So far I've been thinking this:

```
select a.text, replace(b.text,'**',' ')
from table1 a join
     table2 b 
      on a.text like CONCAT('%', b.text, '%');
```

But that doesn't account for `**` words that appear at the beginning of a sentence or before punctuation.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It checks the value of `table2.text` to see if it matches the `**word**` format, and if not, just uses a `LIKE` compare to see if the word is in `table1.text`. If `table2.text` matches the `**word**` format, it uses a `REGEXP` test to ensure that `table2.text` only occurs in `table1.text` as a whole word (using the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word delimiters). I've put some sample data to demonstrate in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d05d32/6).

```
SELECT a.text, REPLACE(b.text, '**', '')
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON b.text NOT REGEXP('\\*\\*[a-z]+\\*\\*') AND a.text LIKE CONCAT('%', b.text, '%') OR
   a.text REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', REPLACE(b.text, '**', ''), '[[:>:]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I figure out your issue, it will be something like this, maybe.

```
SELECT a.text, replace(b.text,'**',' ')
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (a.text, b.text);
```